# Set timeout for large file download

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have a ASPX WebForms site where the user can request a file download. The download link is a LinkButton that calls `Response.Redirect()` to a `.ashx` file.

I need to modify it so that if it doesn't return in 20 seconds, it makes a different call to a webservice that queues the request for asynchronous processing. The problem is, I don't know how to set the timeout of a Response.Redirect.

The only place I know to set a timeout is a JQuery.Ajax call, which does not seem to download the file at all. I also need to be able to test for the timeout so I can make the alternate call and adjust the UI. I have some leeway in how I can structure it; for example, I read a blog saying to create an iframe and set iframe.src to the downloader .ashx. This works, but again I can't specify a timeout.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this solves your problem but you can set the timeout for a page in web.config. For example,

```
 <location path="Page.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime executionTimeout="60" />
    </system.web>
</location>
```

[ASP.NET HTTP runtime settings.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: It might be helpful, but I don't see how it would help me trap the error. I have to be able to test something in JQuery to see if the request has timed out.

Comment: Instead of having the link do a Response.Redirect could you have it call a Web Method on the page to download the file and set the executionTimeout for the page? If the timeout is reached I think jQuery's ajax call would trap the error and you could handle it with its error property then.